# timer based azure function on app service free tier not triggering

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a node js azure function that runs on an App Service Plan.
The function app has only one timer function that triggers once a day.
It was running on an S1 but I downgraded it to the free tier (F1).

After changing the plan, the timer function does not trigger automatically anymore.
It only triggers when I log in to the portal and "wake the function up".

Is this a limitation of the Free Tier? I couldn't find documentation about it.

Comment: yeah i do think you need a dedciated plan to run that: at least a b1 or a consumption plan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is a limitation. The free tier is not "always on" so it unloads the web app when there is no traffic.  You are also limited to 60 minutes compute time per day.

Comment: This ☝. It might be more interesting to run the Function in a Consumption plan, since this also has a free grant of 400,000 GB/s and 1 million executions per month. More details here: [Pricing - Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/)